# netbeans warning: "Utility class without constructor"

Tags: java, netbeans

I have this convenience, utility class for displaying error messages in my Swing app:

```
public class ErrorMessage {
    public static void error(Component parent, String message){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, message, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

However, NetBeans (not compiler) gives a warning:

> ```
> Utility class without constructor
> ```

I know I can turn off the warning, but I'm wondering: what is the point of the warning? Alt+Enter shows me that Netbeans wants me to create a private constructor:

```
private ErrorMessage() {
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that no one accidentally creates an instance of the `ErrorMessage` class. Because the constructor is private, it cannot be instantiated. Great hint, now that I realize what it's for.